# Compilation error when using vector from Stroustrup's PPP book with initializer list

Tags: c++, visual-studio

My code:

```
#define _SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS
#include "c:\Users\1\documents\visual studio 2015\std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    vector<int> v = { 5, 7, 9, 4, 6, 8 };
    return 0;
}
```

fails to compile with this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Detail Description
Error (active)      no instance of constructor "Vector<T>::Vector [with T=int]" matches the argument list   ConsoleApplication1 c:\Users\1\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Source.cpp 6                   argument types are: (int, int, int, int, int, int)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is c++11 enabled with your compiler?

Comment: What's `std_lib_facilities.h`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ There's no way to disable it in VS; and if the OP is really using VS2015, they have `{}` support.

Comment: Also, use the update header that matches your edition of the book ([here](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/std_lib_facilities.h)) so you can get rid of that define.

Comment: @Angew It comes with the book. [Version OP should use](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/std_lib_facilities.h), [version they are using](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you use wrong version of std_lib_facilities.h.`Vector` from that [std_lib_facilities.h](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h) have no `initializer_list` constructor. So you can't do that with this version of header.

```
// trivially range-checked vector (no iterator checking):
template< class T> struct Vector : public std::vector<T> {
    typedef typename std::vector<T>::size_type size_type;

    Vector() { }
    explicit Vector(size_type n) :std::vector<T>(n) {}
    Vector(size_type n, const T& v) :std::vector<T>(n,v) {}
    template <class I>
    Vector(I first, I last) :std::vector<T>(first,last) {}

    T& operator[](unsigned int i) // rather than return at(i);
    {
        if (i<0||this->size()<=i) throw Range_error(i);
        return std::vector<T>::operator[](i);
    }
    const T& operator[](unsigned int i) const
    {
        if (i<0||this->size()<=i) throw Range_error(i);
        return std::vector<T>::operator[](i);
    }
};

// disgusting macro hack to get a range checked vector:
#define vector Vector
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong version of Stroustrup's header. The one you use belongs with the first edition of PPP, use the new one from [here](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/std_lib_facilities.h) and the code works fine.

Then you can also get rid of that legacy fix

```
#define _SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS
```